# Set a variable equal to ajax output that only changes when called

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

I have a radio and am working on the "last song" part of the script. What I want to do is: 
Get a url from my external php script, play the song, at the end of the song set a global variable = the current url by calling a function, when the url changes, the global variable stays the same until the function has been called again and it updates with the current song.

Currently all of my attempts are returning an undefined or "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" in the example below.

```
var data = $.ajax({
url: '../scripts/radio.php',
data: {
attr1: 'value1'
},
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
}
});

function playFirst(){

var lastSong = data;
document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = data;
fileChosen = true;
setupAudioNodes();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

request.open('GET', data, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

// When loaded decode the data
request.onload = function() {

$("#title").html("Infinite");
$("#album").html("Infinite");
$("#artist").html("");
onWindowResize();
$("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

// decode the data
context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
// when the audio is decoded play the sound
sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
sourceNode.start(0);
$("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");
//on error
}, function(e) {
console.log(e);
});
};
request.send();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is returned inside the `success` callback. Since you have not stored the returned `data`, it remains `undefined` when `playFirst()` is called.

You may store the returned `data` in a global variable, like this:

```
let data;
$.ajax({
    url: '../scripts/radio.php',
    data: {
        attr1: 'value1'
    },
    success: function(returnData) {
        data = returnData;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Or call `playFirst()` inside the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../scripts/radio.php',
    data: {
        attr1: 'value1'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        playFirst(data);
    }
});
```